# javascript ajax call via fetch with only method POST : weird behaviour there is post followed by get plus request again all resources?

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, get, fetch-api

I have a form with 2 input they both have `onchange="fetchajax(...);"` but when I look in the network section in chrome inspector, I noticed some weird behaviour....

```
//javascript fecth looks like this
function fetchajax() { fetch(".....php, { method: "POST",}).then(.......); }
```

**--- this is when the page loads**
[image]

**••• when I enter text in input1 => the network in inspector shows me a POST followed by a GET and re ask all resources ??? see this image**
[image]

**••• but when I type some text in input 2; there is only a POST request**
[image]

**** bug ??? why on earth there's POST followed by a GET ??? with the GET I see the text that was typed, but not with POST...

Is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the "why" but I think it maybe unfixable...

it's because the input1 was inside a `<form></form>`

the fact that it's in a form, when I hit enter it wants to send it... so it does a get request by design :(

reading a bit more I found this `<form method="post">`

at least, with specifying method="post" in the form tag, the data in the inputs will pass inside the post (more secure than get...)